# Haskell function overloading

Tags: haskell

1. I have to overload function ordering. The argument of the function is a number and they have to be ordered by their value for the argument `0`. This is what I tried:

   ```
   Prelude>instance (Num a, Ord b) => Ord (a -> b) where f > g = f 0 > g 0
   ```

   but it generates the error

   ```
   Could not deduce (Eq (a -> b))
   arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
   from the context (Num a, Ord b)
   bound by the instance declaration at <interactive>:117:10-39
   In the instance declaration for `Ord (a -> b)'
   ```
2. I would also like to instantiate the Ord class for lists. Lists ordering will be given by the comparison between first element of each list. For example [1,2] < [2,3] because 1 < 2.

   ```
   instance Ord a => Ord [a] where
       (h1:_) <= (h2:_) = h1 <= h2
   ```

   This also generates the next error:

   ```
   Ambiguous occurrence `<='
   It could refer to either `Main.<=',
                        defined at C:\Users\user-name\Desktop\test.hs:2:8
                     or `Prelude.<=',
                        imported from `Prelude' at C:\Users\user-name\Desktop\test.hs:1:1
                        (and originally defined in `GHC.Classes')
   ```

I think I may have not understood very well the function overloading in Haskell. Maybe someone could explain me what I do wrong.

Comment: Do you define your own `<=` ? Prelude already comes with a `<=` so you should choose which one you want (that is what the second error message is saying). The first error is saying that there is no built in definition for equality between functions. Also, Haskell does not have function overloading.

Comment: your ordering for the list will be very strange because then `[1,1] <= [1,2]` and `[1,2] <= [1,1]` but of course `[1,1] /= [1,2]` - also you cannot compare empty lists ... why would you do this?

Comment: The purpose of the exercise is to understand the principle not to do something that "makes sense".

Comment: your exercise wants you to grapple with three things: defining a function `<=`, which will (try to) work for all types of arguments; defining a new type's instance of `Ord` type class (your case 1); and defining an existing type's instance (for `[a]`) (your 2) which won't work even if you hadn't defined the function `<=` before, because there already exists an instance for `Ord a => Ord [a]` in the `Prelude`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't do this. You're defining orphan instances here (instances that live neither in the module of the `data` nor the `class` they belong to); such instances are “invisible” in imports, which is generally a pain for larger project maintenance. (Sometimes you won't get around orphan instances, in particular when combining data and classes from unrelated packages; but functions, lists and `Ord` are all in the base library. If an instance isn't defined there, you can be pretty sure that there's a good reason!
2. If you do define a class instance, look at the class definition! `Ord` is defined thus:

   ```
   class (Eq a) => Ord a where
     ...
   ```

   that means, any instance of `Ord` must be an instance of `Eq` too. This is also what the compiler is telling you. So, if you do define this instance, you also need to add

   ```
   instance (Num a, Eq b) => Eq (a -> b) where f==g = f 0 == g 0
   ```

   This is the only instance that is compatible with your `Ord`. Frankly, it's just wrong though, since most functions that are deemed equal by this instance are *not* equal!
3. Haskell does *not* have overloading as such, at all. If you define a function `<=` in your module `Main`, this is a completely unrelated function from the standard `<=` aka `Prelude.<=`. You can define such a new function, but to use it you will need to disambiguate. The following should work:

   ```
   instance Ord a => Ord [a] where
     (h1:_) <= (h2:_) = h1 Main.<= h2
   ```

   again though, this is not a good idea – you simply shouldn't define `Main.<=` in the first place, but put its definition right in the `Ord` instance.

Comment: Wouldn't the `Ord [a]` instance overlap with the `Prelude` instance?

Comment: I understood now what you're telling at 2. I have one more question. Why does this work `instance (Show b, Num a) => Show (a -> b) where show f = show (f 0)` and I don't have to do `instance (Show b, Num a) => Show (a -> b) where show f = Main.show (f 0)`?

Comment: Because unlike with `<=`, which you apparently tried to define anew yourself, you never defined your own `show` function. Hence it's clear that `show` refers to `Prelude.show`, whereas `Main.show` simply doesn't exist.

Comment: `Main.show` will not work. The only `show` in scope is `Prelude.show`. Prelude is automatically imported so you can just do `show`.